# Batch file that will create directory and place a txt file inside with specific name

Tags: windows, command-line

This is what I have, but I want the text file to go in to the Log file directory with out giving full paths.

```
@echo off
set dirname=
:input
set /P dirname=Type directory name: %=%
if "%dirname%"=="" goto input

mkdir "%dirname%"_Archive
mkdir "%dirname%"_Errors
mkdir "%dirname%"_Inbound
mkdir "%dirname%"_Outbound
mkdir LogFiles

set text name=
@CON >> "%dirname%"_LogFile.txt

set text name=
:input
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "with out giving full paths"?  `@CON >> %dirname%\LogFiles\_LogFile.txt` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @techie007: Not sure about that part of the question either, but doubtful your suggestion would work unless there happened to already be an existing directory named `%dirname%\LogFiles` since the script isn't creating one.

Comment: @martineau Good catch.

Comment: Although -- surprisingly to me -- the commands like `mkdir "%dirname%"_Archive` where you have a quote in the middle of a path appear to work and be ignored, I think it would be safer and more correct to use `mkdir "%dirname%_Archive"`, `mkdir "%dirname%_Errors"`, etc.

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: @Techturnal: Which is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm a little unsure about what you're asking, but think maybe you need to add a line with `chdir Logfiles` right after the one with `mkdir LogFiles` or right before the `@CON >> "%dirname%_LogFile.txt"`.  This causes the file which is being created in the current directory do so in the `Logfiles` directory.

Don't know what you're doing with the `set text name=` commands, nor the effect having duplicate `:input` labels might have.

Comment: Following the correct logic you've pointed out, instead of the change dir perhaps a reference to the current folder, `@CON >> .\Logfiles\_Logfile.txt`?  Regardless, I agree there's a couple freaky things happening in this script. ;)

Comment: so I create a directory %dirname% which also creates a text file that follows I need to fall into the newly director named LogFiles. that's it the rest workd I'm just stumped on getting the txt file in the dir.Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Techturnal: I'm confused. Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Techturnal: You could use another `set /P` to get the 'text name' into a variable and then `echo "%text_name%" >> "LogFiles\%dirname%_LogFile.txt"` (or wherever - it's unclear where you want the file).

Comment: YES! this works now!

@CON >> .\LogFiles\%dirname%"_LogFile.txt

Comment: @Techturnal: Oh, so _that's_ what what you were trying to do... ;-)